# Boolean Algebra Simplification POS

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm given this expression
$$
(x+y'+z')(x'+z')
$$
the $'$ meaning not. I have to simplify this to 3 literals and show my answer as a product of sums.

Every calculator I check says the answer is $(x'y')+z'$. So far all I can think of to do as the first step is to expand the given expression using distribution giving me
$$
xx'+xz'+x'y'+y'z'+x'z'+z'z'.
$$
From there I know $xx'$ is $1$ and $z'z'$ is $z'$, giving me $xz'+x'y'+y'z'+x'z'+z'$ and this is where I get stuck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know what absorption is?

Comment: Please explain? A way to absorb like terms? Am I going about this completely wrong?

Comment: No, you're pretty close to the target.  Absorption says that $a + ab$ simplifies to $a$.

Comment: So could I say z'+x'z'= x'?

Comment: No, that is incorrect.  What is $a$ and what is $b$ in your case?

Comment: Would it be my a is z' and my b is x' therefore it becomes z'+x'z'=z'?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expression $xx'$ means “$x$ is true and not $x$ is true”, so $xx'=0$.
Thus the expression is:
$$
xz'+x'y'+y'z'+x'z'+z'z'=(x+x')z'+x'y'+y'z'+z'=
x'y' + (y'+1)z'=x'y'+z'
$$

Answer (score 0):

A useful principle is:

**Reduction**

$x(x'+z) = x + z$  (given $x$, the $x'+z$ term reduces to just $z$)

So:

$$(x+y'+z')(x'+z') = (x+y')x'+z'=y'x'+z'$$